# How to make the pressing of a button keep an event occurring at a controlled rate?

Tags: dynamic

Suppose I use a `Button[]` to make some event occur, how can I make the pressing of this button keep that event occurring at a controlled rate? I tried the following:

```
x = 0;
Button["X", Dynamic[Refresh[x = x + 1, UpdateInterval -> 1]]]
Dynamic[x]
```

But it doesn't keep repeating the event `x=x+1` if the button keeps pressed. If there is some neater/better alternative without `Button[]`, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to control the rate using a `Checkbox` control.

```
Clear[delay, dt, flag, prev, x]
dt = 1;
flag = False;
prev = AbsoluteTime[] ;
x = 0;
delay := If[AbsoluteTime[] >= prev + dt && flag,
    prev = AbsoluteTime[]; True,
    False]
Row[{Checkbox[Dynamic[flag]], " Click to run"}] // Framed
Dynamic[Refresh[If[delay, x = x + 1, x], UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

There are other controls besides `Checkbox` that might do a better job.  The timing could also be improved.  The counter is immediately updated as soon as it is clicked on.  Maybe it should wait 1 second.  Then, it seems to wait an extra second before it starts regular counting.